# it Give my Error when i Use iteration With Files

Tags: python

hi guys i have in my mind idea

the idea is make a Scripts change  `'\n' to range(len(b+1)` in file (txt)

Note : the Scripts is not complete yet

this is the code of Scripts

code of Scripts:

```
a = open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/b.txt","r") # Include File for read ('r')
b = a.readlines()                            # doing list 
c = len(b)                                  # len the number of elements in list
e = list(range(len(b)+1))             # doing list of numbers it start from 0 to (len(b)+1)
t = 0                                        # Variable use in loop(while)
while t<len(b):                              # loop is True if t < len(b)
    for i in range(len(b)+1):          # iteration  from 0 to  len(b)+1 using range()
        if b[i]=='\n':                       # use if  Statement,
            b[i]=e[i]                        # change '\n' to a numbre (i)
    t=t+1
for i in b:
    print(i)                              # Print each element using iterator
```

when i try to run the Scripts it gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1.py", line 8, in <module>
    if b[i]=='\n':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The contents of the file :

```
'\n'
00:00:00
string
'\n'
00:00:19
string
```

NOTE :

string = it mean the text in file

this file is for Translation a video

but the file dont have 1,2,3,4,5...

and i cant add  1,2,3,4,5... using myself it Hard

what i need :

how to fix it

and better idea to this Scripts

Comment: You dont need to add 1 to len(b).  Range(len(b))

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
for i in range(len(b)):
```

Rather then :

```
for i in range(len(b)+1):
```

i.e)

List index are 0 based that is they start from 0

```
a=[1,2,3]
len(a)
3
range(len(a))
[0,1,2]
range(len(a)+1)
[0,1,2,3]
a[3]
Error list index out of range
```

**In your code you are iterating from 0 to len(b)+1**

```
for i in range(len(b)+1):
```

Suppose `if len(b) is 3`

```
for i in range(len(b)+1):
    print i
0
1
2
3
```

And if you try to get the index of a list which is not created then index out of range error is thrown

That is you are trying to index a list which not created

```
b[3]
Error index out of range
```

i.e.)

```
b=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(b)):
    print i,b[i]

0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
for i in range(len(b)+1):
    print i,b[i]

0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: if you can explain to me

Comment: *"could you accept it and wait I am still editing"* - why should they accept an answer you admit you haven't finished.

Comment: @VigneshKalai I've read all of the comments, and hassling users to accept your answer is extremely bad form (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271815/3001761). Please stop doing it. (Also the question is a car wreck and you should have VTC rather than answering.)

Comment: @VigneshKalai asking, *once* is sometimes acceptable, for example if it's been a while and the OP has got a working answer they haven't accepted. *"could you accept it"*, *"it would be good if you can accept the answer"*, *"then accept after 6 minutes"* is **absolutely not**. The 15 minutes is there for a reason, and even if your answer does answer the question others may provide a better one, you shouldn't be trying to shut them out.

Comment: @KhalidEs-safi does it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to add line numbers for empty lines? If so the following might be suitable?

```
with open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/b.txt","r") as a:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(a):
        if line == "\n":
            print line_number+1
        else:
            print line,
```

Which would give the following type of output:

```
line1
2
3
line4
```

Comment: ya it work 2 but i cant use my self it has input ther

Comment: @KhalidEs-safi ...what?

Answer (score 0):

try to use re module should help and put your regex as ^\n$ and erase it that should help u in your program +

try to use

```
for i in range(len(b)):
```

to fix your problem